# UpdateLayeredWindow and 16bit display color depth

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, windows-7, windows-xp, gdi

Works fine with 32bit colors.
When switching to 16bit, window that was painted with UpdateLayeredWindow gets messed. You can click through and/or colors get changed.

Works bad with my own source code and also with others. For example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20758/Alpha-Blended-Windows-Forms

Tested on Windows7 and XP.

How to rid of this behaviour. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Alpha blending and Alpha transparency doesn't work with 16-bit color depths since there is no Alpha channel to work with.  You need 32-bit color depths in order to have an Alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

I've googled around, and this works for me

http://www.myexception.cn/vc-mfc/170082.html

The idea is DO NOT create compatible bitmap when in 16bit mode, but explicitly create 32bit one.